# Android: Matching host pattern in an Intent Filter

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have the following URL:

```
http://api.modarchive.org/downloads.php?moduleid=50479#ngs_cvrg.xm
```

What I would like to do is match all .php URLs which contain 'mod' in the hostname. android:host will only allow 1 wildcard and I need 2.

I have tried modifying android:pathPattern instead as follows:

```
<data android:pathPattern=".*mod.*\\.php"/>
```

What is wrong with the above statement?

If I were to write a 'normal' file wildcard for doing this, I would be using:

```
 *mod*.php
```

..but Android pathPattern syntax is different.

It would seem that what I am trying to do isn't possible:

```
"The URL consists of four parts: it has each of the four properties scheme, host, port, path corresponds to the URI part.

       For example: content://com.wjr.example1:121/files

       Part scheme: content
       Part host: com.wjr.example1
       Part port: 121
       Part path: files 
"
```

So.. how can I match any host containing "mod" (e.g. mods, modules, modarchive, modheaven etc) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this.  Presumably this prevents any app from registering essentially "bulk" interceptors for URLs and confusing users who might see some strange app asking to handle all sorts of URLs.  You'll have to register each one by specific name.

Comment: Yeah, its frustrating that you cannot match on URL parameters. If I could add a pattern for something that follows the '?' in a PHP URL, all my troubles would be solved. Hopefully this one website is the exception that I have to cater for :)